# How to randomly pick one object from a loop that determines smallest value, if 1+ instances have the same (smallest) value?

Tags: java, arrays, random, foreach, seed

I have written a Java program that consist of three relevant classes; Employee, Client & Contract. In my main method I have created an array of various instances of all 3 classes as so;

```
// Create Clients
Client Client1 = new Client(1, "Client 1", 0);
Client Client2 = new Client(2, "Client 2", 0);

// Create Array of Clients
Client[] clients = new Client[] {Client1, Client2};

// Create Contracts
Contract Contract1 = new Contract("Contract 1", 1, 850, 4, 0, 1, 0);
Contract Contract2 = new Contract("Contract 2", 2, 500, 4, 0, 1, 0);
Contract Contract3 = new Contract("Contract 3", 3, 1500, 3, 0, 1, 0);

// Create Array of Contracts
Contract[] contracts = new Contract[] {Contract1, Contract2, Contract3};

// Create Employees
Employee Employee1 = new Employee(1, "Bradley", 0);
Employee Employee2 = new Employee(2, "Patrick", 0);
Employee Employee3 = new Employee(3, "Erin", 0);
Employee Employee4 = new Employee(4, "Jim", 0);
Employee Employee5 = new Employee(5, "Fredrick", 0);

// Create Array of Employees
Employee[] employees = new Employee[] {Employee1, Employee2, Employee3, Employee4, Employee5};
```

I have a function in Contract.Java called assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts which takes 2 arguments, an array of employees, and contract. The function is:

```
// Assign contract to employee with least contracts
public void assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts(Employee[] employees, Contract contract) {

    // Assign to employee with minimum contracts
    int minContract = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Employee employeeWithMinContracts = null;
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if (employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() < minContract) {
            // swap min and employee if true
            employeeWithMinContracts = employee;
            minContract = employeeWithMinContracts.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts();
        }
    }

    employeeWithMinContracts.assignContract(employeeWithMinContracts, contract);
}
```

The problem I have is I need to handle what happens if 2 employees both have the same (minimum) number of contracts assigned. How can I pick one of the employees at random if this happens? I have tried implementing a seed within the foreach loop but keep breaking everything.

Any help would be appriciated,

Thanks, 
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Java 8 or above something like below could be more readable:

```
public void assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts(Employee[] employees, Contract contract) {
    int minContract =  Arrays.stream(employees)
            .mapToInt(Employee::getCurrentlyAssignedContracts)
            .min()
            .getAsInt();
    Employee employeeWithMinContracts = Arrays.stream(employees)
            .filter(e->e.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() == minContract)
            .findAny()
            .get();

    employeeWithMinContracts.assignContract(employeeWithMinContracts, contract);
}
```

**EDIT**

While `findAny()` in above solution behaves explicitly nondeterministic, i.e. it is free to select any element in the stream, leting you no controll of the likelihood of an element being choosen; you might want to have an equally distributed probability. If that is the case see the second solution below:

```
public void assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts(Employee[] employees, Contract contract) {
    int minContract =  Arrays.stream(employees)
            .mapToInt(Employee::getCurrentlyAssignedContracts)
            .min()
            .getAsInt();
    List<Employee> minEmployees =  Arrays.stream(employees)
            .filter(e->e.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() == minContract)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Random r = new Random();
    Employee employeeWithMinContracts = minEmployees.get(r.nextInt(minEmployees.size()));

    employeeWithMinContracts.assignContract(employeeWithMinContracts, contract);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the revision, the first was satisfactory but interesting and helpful none the less

Answer (score 3):

If you expect more than two employees to share the same number of minimum contracts, then you need to randomly pick among them. You can do this by making a list of the minimum contracts and picking one at random.

```
    // Assign contract to employee with least contracts
public void assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts(Employee[] employees, Contract contract) {

    // Find the employees with the minimum contracts
    int minContract = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List <Employee> employeesWithMinContracts = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        //add duplicates to the list
        if (employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() == minContract) {
            employeesWithMinContracts.add(employee);
        }
        // swap min and employee if true
        if (employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() < minContract) {
            employeesWithMinContracts.clear();
            employeesWithMinContracts.add(employee);
            minContract = employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts();
        }
    }

    //Randomly pick an employee from the group.
    int random = (int)(Math.random() *  employeesWithMinContracts.size() );

    employeeWithMinContracts.assignContract(employeesWithMinContracts.get(random), contract);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help, I udnerstand the logic.. when I tried to use your adjusted version of the function I got 'can't resolve symbol' on employeeWithMinContracts and on .size on the final line, do you know why this is?

Comment: I added Employee employeeWithMinContracts = null; before the for loop, so now I've just got the can't resolve on .size of employeesWithMinContracts

Comment: @bbowesbo Yes, be cautious. This code needs a few modifications. As it is right now, the code won't compile and the contract assignment will not work.

Comment: Sorry about that. The .size shouldn't have been on that line. It was a copy paste error. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, in your `assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts` method you want to randomly assign the Contract to either one of the Employees if they have the same amount of Contracts.
Because currently you will assign it to the first Employee with the lowest amount of Contracts.

Your method would then become this:

```
public void assignContractToEmployeeWithLeastContracts(Employee[] employees, Contract contract) {
    int minContract = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Employee> employeesWithMinContracts = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if (employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() < minContract) {
            employeesWithMinContracts.clear();
            employeesWithMinContracts.add(employee);
            minContract = employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts();
        } else if (employee.getCurrentlyAssignedContracts() == minContract) {
            employeesWithMinContracts.add(employee);
        }
    }
    int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * employeesWithMinContracts.size());
    employeesWithMinContracts.get(randomIndex).assignContract(contract);
}
```

We'll makes use of the fact the `Math.random` returns a value between [0, 1] and thus will find our employeesWithMinContracts list index randomly.

Remarks:

- Notice that I removed the `Employee` as argument on the `assignContract` method. Since this method is already called on the `Employee` in question.
- Also your instance names should start with a lowercase to adhere to the Java standards:
  `Contract1` becomes `contract1`
  `Employee1` becomes `employee1`
  etc...

Comment: Wouldn't this still give an unequal chance to the employees? The last one has a 50% chance of being chosen, but the one before that had a 50% chance of being chosen at that time followed by a 50% chance of being replaced?

So if there are 5 employee's with the minimum number of contracts, the first one in the list would need to pass 4 random checks to retain the contract, the second one would need to pass 3 random checks and so on

Comment: @Piers Unequal chances are what drive our Employees to fight for each Contract. This is a cutthroath business, you know! :P  But seriously, I edited the code to give everyone a fair shot.

Comment: This is better than my solution since it checks `< minContract` first and only checks `== minContract` on the else. Also, it compiles.